# Questions that just get Closed

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I find it common that people ask for ideas for their project.  If they ask it on Blender.stackexchange, they get closed for being "to broad" or "off topic".  Then there are times when people ask for help, say, for a project.  They want a modeler, or an animator, to help them with their project.  These questions also get closed.  It's understandable why, but is there a place where we can get these questions answered?

Is there a separate place on stackexchange that allows users to ask so-called "off topic" questions?  It would be nice to be able to get ideas or help from people off of stack exchange, without having to find another site.
Thankyou

Comment: Ideas, suggestions and artistic input are subjective and opinion based and don't have a "right answer", and as such [are not a good fit for our site](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). For that you can try the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=blender.stackexchange.com) or other forums like https://blenderartists.org or various communities

Comment: I was afraid of that.

Comment: This site is not a **forum**. It is a simple question and answers site. Posts that don't fit that format are considered off topic. For "conversations" or more relaxed rules, you can use chat, but even that is limited for users with a minimum reputation. A forum format is better for that kind of exchanges.

Comment: got yah, thanks for the response